# Create objects in for loop

Tags: python, django

How to create ten `User` objects?

```
for i in range(11):
    i = User.objects.create(username = 'test125', email='test@mail.com', password='pass1')
```

Column `username` is not unique

Comment: username='test{}'.format(i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a unique contraint on the `username` field which means you cannot have two objects with the same `username`. Try this:

```
for i in range(10):
    i = User.objects.create(username = 'testX%s' % i, email='test@mail.com', password='pass1')
```

Comment: Depending on how many times you're going to loop [bulk create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.bulk_create) would limit hitting the database too much.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you fixed the `username` value, so you are trying to create 10 users with the same name.

Just use some kind of variation for the username, like `username='testuser-{}'.format(i)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name for each record.

You are naming each user "test125". Try concatenating the index for each new record:

```
for i in range(11):
    i = User.objects.create(username = 'test%s' % i, email='test@mail.com', password='pass1')
```

Most likely you will need to do the same with your 'email' column:

```
for i in range(11):
    i = User.objects.create(username = 'test%s' % i, email='test%s@mail.com' % i, password='pass1')
```

Also, usually is not a good idea to assign your new object to the same variable as your index. Try something different than 'i'.