# form instance inside loop django

Tags: django, loops

I'm looking to save my form instance and I found [Create objects in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14504774/create-objects-in-for-loop).

How can I achieve similar effect if I have:

```
pk = self.kwargs['pk']
C =  {'dog':'Nash', 'cat':'Luffy'}
for animal,owner in C.items():
    form.instance.owner = owner
    form.instance.animal = animal
    form.instance.patient = Clinic.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

Comment: why don't you directly save the objects from its model reference? Why use the form?

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you expound.

Comment: You can directly save the objects. Like, ModelName.objects.create(owner=owner, animal=animal, ...) in the for loop.

Comment: I added my answer below, It went well except that it creates 2 extra empty record.

Comment: I found out that the extra records is not from my form_valid. I wonder where can I start tracing it.